# Scrolling through data only in core plot iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Currently I'm using core plot cocoa pod to draw a scatter graph, currently I need scrolling to be enabled **but** at the same time I need the x & y axis the be fixed on the corner of the screen and only move through data any way to do this ?.
My current implementation for the following code makes me scrolls through data but x-axis or y-axis disappears when I scroll far through the graph

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
CPTGraphHostingView* hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview: hostView];

// Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
CPTGraph* graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostView.bounds];
hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

// Get the (default) plotspace from the graph so we can set its x/y ranges
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;

// Note that these CPTPlotRange are defined by START and LENGTH (not START and END) !!
[plotSpace setYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]]];

[plotSpace setXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]]];

plotSpace.delegate = self;

graph.paddingLeft   = 10.0;
graph.paddingRight  = 10.0;
graph.paddingTop    = 10.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 10.0;

// Create the plot (we do not define actual x/y values yet, these will be supplied by the datasource...)
CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

// Let's keep it simple and let this class act as datasource (therefore we implemtn <CPTPlotDataSource>)
plot.dataSource = self;

// Finally, add the created plot to the default plot space of the CPTGraph object we created before
[graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axisConstraints`:

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:0.0];
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:0.0];
```

Use 0.0 to place the axis to the left (y-axis) or bottom (x-axis). Use 1.0 to place the axis to the right (y-axis) or top (x-axis). Any fraction between 0.0 and 1.0 is valid.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Skroch, it worked, for me :)
currently I need to set upper and lower ranges for the axis, so if a label beyond these limit it will disappear, my current implementation puts an end to the drawing data, but not for the axis labels